Drawing text over a shader
I have been going through Ebitengine's great tutorial for Kage https://github.com/tinne26/kage-desk/blob/main/docs/tutorials/intro/00_introduction.md (it's own shading language), and haven't been able to find a way to integrate text, without making a formula to draw letters. That wouldn't be problematic, but I've found that trying to draw over a shader doesn't seem to work.
Pseudo code:
screen.Drawtriangles(...)
text.Draw(...)

Even though text.Draw is called second, the shader is called on top.
